# ellipses word loading screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is make a loading screen that shows some message, and a flashing ellipses. It would look like this, but more animated:

```
Crunching data.
Crunching data..
Crunching data...
Crunching data.
Crunching data..
```

currently, I have the following code, but it crashes the site, so I'd say it's fair to assume it doesn't work:

```
function loader(div) {
  div.append('<div id="loader"></div>');
  load = div.find('#loader');
  load.html('Crunching Some Data.');
  numberOfPeriods = 1;
  while($('#loader').length > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if(numberOfPeriods < 4) {
        numberOfPeriods++;
        for(var i=0; i<numberOfPeriods; i++) {
          load.append('.');
        }
      } else {
        load.html('Crunching Some Data.');
        numberOfPeriods = 1;
      }
    }, 200);
  }
}
```

how would one go about doing this?

Comment: `while($('#loader').length > 0) {` This would be why....

Comment: I imagine that it is going into an infinite loop, but I am not sure HOW to loop it by timeslices of x milliseconds appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
function showLoader() {
    var load;
    load = $('<div id="loader"></div>');
    $(document.body).append(load);
    load.html('Crunching Some Data.');
    numberOfPeriods = 1;

    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(numberOfPeriods < 4)
        {
            load.html(load.html() + '.');
            numberOfPeriods++;
        }
        else
        {
            load.html('Crunching Some Data.');
            numberOfPeriods = 1;
        }
    }, 200);
}

function hideLoader(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    $('#loader').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put setTimeout inside a loop.  Instead, test for the "done" condition at the top of the function called by setTimeout (test the length of #loader).  If not done, use setTimeout again.  If done, call a function which moves things along.